# Functions that converts day of year to month and day and reverse with error checking

Tags: c, beginner, datetime, error-handling

> There is no error checking in `day_of_year` or `month_day`. remedy this defect.

Here is the solution:

```
int day_of_year(unsigned int year, unsigned int month, int day) {
    int leap, i;

    leap = ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));

    if(((month >= 1) && (month <= 12)) && ((day >= 1) && (day <= daytab[leap][month]))) {
        for(i = 1; i < month; i++) {
            day += daytab[leap][i];
        }

        return day;
    }

    return -1;

}

void month_day(unsigned int year, unsigned int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday) {
    int leap, i;

    leap = ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
    if((leap == 1 && (yearday >= 1 && yearday <= 366)) || (leap == 0 && (yearday >= 1 && yearday <= 366))) {

        for(i = 1; yearday > daytab[leap][i]; i++) {
          yearday -= daytab[leap][i];
        }
        *pday = yearday;
        *pmonth = i;
    }
    else {
        printf("error: the yearday is invalid");
    }
}
```

In the `day_of_year`'s case I have to check if the `yearday` is a valide one. `1 <= yearday <= (365 || 366)`. I changed the parameters type to unsigned, because a day can't be negative nor a year.

In the `month_day`'s case I check if the `month` is a valid one, it should be `1 <= month <= 12`. After this, I check if the `day` belongs to a valid interval.

This exercise can be found in K&R2 at page 126.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Incorrect `yearday` limit

   ```
   // if((leap == 1 ... || (leap == 0 && (yearday >= 1 && yearday <= 366))) {
   if((leap == 1 ... || (leap == 0 && (yearday >= 1 && yearday <= 365))) {
   //                                                             365
   ```
2. `month_day()` and `day_of_year()` should use consistent types for `month`.  Suggest `int` for both.

   ```
   // int day_of_year(unsigned int year, unsigned int month, int day) {
   // void month_day(unsigned int year, unsigned int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday) {
   int day_of_year(unsigned int year,         int month, int day) {
   ```
3. `month_day()` and `day_of_year()` should use consistent types for `yearday`.  Suggest `int` for both.

   ```
   // int day_of_year(unsigned int year, unsigned int month, int day) {
   // void month_day(unsigned int year, unsigned int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday) {
   int day_of_year(unsigned int year, int month, int day) {
   void month_day(unsigned int year, int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday) {
   ```
4. Leap year calculation `leap = ((year...` is good back to 1583.  For years 4 to 1582 it is  `leap = (year % 4 == 0);`  1582 has other complications.  Before 4 has complications.
5. Suggest `month_day()` return `int` to indicate success or failure.

Comment: if `yearday` will be an int the user may pass negative values. Should I modify my function such that it will handle a negative`yearday`?

Comment: @Ionut Grt.  Suggest that a negative `yearday` is treated like 0 or 367+.  Looks like code `yearday >= 1` catches that already.